# windowBackground not picking night color in styles when dark theme enabled

Tags: android, whatsapp, android-dark-theme

i have implemented dark ui in my android app everything is working fine but i have a launcher activity which has `windowBackground` in styles like this

```
   <style name="AppTheme.Launcher" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/l_launch_screen</item>
    </style>
```

and the `l_launch_screen` is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- The android:opacity=”opaque” line — this is critical in preventing a flash of black as your theme transitions. -->
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">

    <!-- The background color, preferably the same as your normal theme -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <!-- Your product logo - 144dp color version of your app icon -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/app_round_icon"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and in this `colorPrimaryDark` has two color one is night and other is simple
now the issue is that when the dark theme is activated by android by selecting `Dark theme` in android q notification panel `android:windowBackground` is picking night color but when `Dark theme` is disabled by android and dark theme is selected in my app by setting this in application class

```
   AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

`android:windowBackground` is not picking the night color but all other activities is picking the night color perfectly I have seen the same behavior with `WhatsApp` app so is this a bug or i am doing something wrong I have also tried define different styles for the night and for drawable but happening the same issue

Comment: You have told it what color to use regardless of theme: ```@color/colorPrimaryDark```

Comment: @PrinceAli colorPrimaryDark  has two color one fore night and one for base

Comment: Then you can't use @color , how do you apply the background to other screens?

Comment: i am using android:windowBackground just for my launcher activity not for other activities

Comment: Post your day night theme styles. And if possible, some xml code where you also change colors to some background

Comment: i have posted above android provide us daynight theme  please first read my question carefully i have defined everything

Comment: You need to do it something like this: ```?android:windowBackground``` or ```?colorPrimary```

Comment: You need to enable system-wide dark mode to darken launch screen. App's dark theme doesn't affect launch screens.

Comment: @IrfanLatif can you please explain your answer what do you mean by "system-wide"?

Comment: By system-wide I mean the dark mode introduced in Android 10 which can be turned on from settings or tile.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to implement loading screen using Activities approach.

1. Add 2 new resource files:

- for light theme **splash_background.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

- for dark theme **splash_background.xml** (same name) place it in **drawable-night** folder (create if you dont have it ) and you have to add in **colors.xml** custom dark color (for example `<color name="black_700">#191414</color>`) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/your_dark_background_color" />
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

2. Finally In your themes.xml:

```
    <style name="Theme.AppName.SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppName">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
    </style>
```

3. Good approach to create splashscreen as theme of existing style and show it when app started: to do that create new Activity

```
class SplashScreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppName_SplashTheme)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        startActivity(Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java))
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0) //this one to remove animation
        finish()
    }
}
```

4. Apply this theme on your SplashScreenActivity in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppName.SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

5. In your MainActivity.kt you have to add Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION to remove annoying swipe animation when switching activity:

```
    companion object {
        fun startFrom(context: Context) {
            val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.flags =
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION 
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```